# view specific context processors with flask-classy

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm using Flask + Flask-Classy with jinja2 templates, and I want to inject some data into my templates for all requests in that view (eg, index, get, etc) without having to return it manually on each request.

Right now, if I use @app.context_processor to inject data, even if its defined as a class method inside the view, it gets run and injected for every single view/request (if I go to /signup (SignupView), I get data from /account (AccountView))

Is there any way to do this? Something like

```
class FooView(FlaskView):

    def inject_data(self):
        return dict(bar=123)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's no way to do it with FlaskView, so in the end I just created another layer of blueprints for each subsection. Not ideal but it works.